# Apache is caching virtualhost, how to disable caching?

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, cache

I got the one VirtualHost block in httpd-vhosts.conf working correctly. From an external client, it was correctly forwarding the site name to the proper IP of my backend webserver.

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
ProxyRequests On
ProxyPreserveHost On
ServerName www.domain.com
ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.21
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.21
</VirtualHost>
```

I then REMOVED the entire VirtualHost block, and then ran httpd -k restart (I also tried httpd -k stop, then httpd -k start).

From a different external client, it STILL gets forwarded to the site name I had configured in VirtualHost. Clearing the cache in IE11 and re-running IE11 still gets forwarded to the same site.

It makes testing very difficult!

Comment: **WARNING: DO NOT set `ProxyRequests On`. This opens your server to abuse as an open proxy.** It is also not necessary for a reverse proxy.

Comment: Please read [Forward Proxies and Reverse Proxies/Gateways](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#forwardreverse) to understand the difference. In most cases the [ProxyPreserveHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypreservehost) directive is also not needed (default is `Off`).